# FPDF error: Unsupported image type

Tags: php, fpdf

I am using FPDF to print the pdf version of my webpage.

I am currently using `image` function of FPDF to print out image. I have the following code to print image-

```
function PutImg($URL, $txt)
{
    // Put a image
    $this->Ln(10);
    $start_x = $this->GetX();
    $start_y = $this->GetY();
    $this->Image($URL,$this->GetX(), $this->GetY(),90, 0);
    $this->SetStyle('U',false);
    $this->SetLink($txt);
    $this->SetTextColor(0);
    $this->Ln(10);
}
```

This prints out image successfully if I use the image URL-http://i706.photobucket.com/albums/ww62/fadey86/ifadey%20official%20website/install.jpg. But when I used the URL:
http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT9kiQoy9NiniQqbTSNXRQxeNtnOoXwuZuuYZiJzOV1gbfIZHippBfaZj2FxA

it gives the following error-

```
FPDF error: Unsupported image type: com/images?q=tbn:and9gct9kiqoy9niniqqbtsnxrqxentnooxwuzuuyzijzov1gbfizhippbfazj2fxa
```

Can anyone please explain or can correct it?

**EDIT-**
I have tried to use the image links which only ends on .jpg/.png and then it prints the PDF properly according to my wish. So the problem is for the images whose URLs are not ending in JPG. What for them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like FPDF tries to determine the filetype based on the URI instead of HTTP headers. What happens if you cheat a little bit?

```
http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT9kiQoy9NiniQqbTSNXRQxeNtnOoXwuZuuYZiJzOV1gbfIZHippBfaZj2FxA#.jpg
```

(Note the #.jpg at the end)

Comment: yeah that worked for me. I am getting the pdf but now again, in two tries. On first try, it prompts me to download `download.php` which actually is file where this code lies, then on next try, it prompts the pdf file to download. Can you explain that part?

Comment: Sounds like a browser cache issue... That, or you're sending the wrong headers.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this little hack..It saved me. :)